# IE & Drop Down Menus triggering the Pop-Up Blocker

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, popup, html-select

I have no idea why this is happening.  I have some very straightforward code, replicated below, which works fine in all browsers except for IE 7 & 8.  In those browsers, trying to expand the list of options in the select triggers the built-in Pop-up blocker bar.

What gives?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>
        Test
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/dynamic/main.4d?Support&amp;demo2004_01&amp;RD" method="post" id="signup" name="signup">
        <fieldset id="selects">
            <select name="bedrooms">
                <option selected="selected" value="">
                    Bedrooms *
                </option>
                <option value="0">
                    Studio
                </option>
                <option value="1">
                    1 Bedroom
                </option>
                <option value="1.5">
                    Flex 2 Bedrooms
                </option>
                <option value="2">
                    2 Bedrooms
                </option>
                <option value="2.5">
                    Flex 3 Bedrooms
                </option>
                <option value="3">
                    3 Bedrooms
                </option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you remove the action attribute from the form does it still activate the blocker? That URL looks like a possible culprit...

Comment: No, blanking it out doesn't change the behavior. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I just ran it locally and don't get any issues. Is this absolutely *all* the code? Also, what level of security is your browser set to?

Comment: The security is set to Medium, which I believe is the default for a standard install.  And no, there is no additional code: copying and pasting the above into my browser (7/8) yields the behavior I described.  My concern is that a default install of IE on visitor's machine will act the same as mine.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped - the security is set to Medium-High.

Comment: try setting it to medium

Comment: Try running ad-aware on your machine. Maybe you've got a virus or some trojans.

Comment: Ill delete mine since it is in no way able to help you

Comment: The machine is clean - fresh install.  To the best of your knowledge, IE security settings (or anything else) shouldn't prevent a simple drop down menu like this right? If so, I'll just pass mine up as a fluke.  I just want to make sure my users won't run into this problem as well.

Comment: Nope it shouldn't cause problems. I can't replicate it here on IE 6/7/8. It seems you have the reverse of my favorite quote: "It works on my machine".

Comment: Who would have thunk? You know now that I think about it, I am using TredoSoft MultipleIEs (for IE6) and another hack that allows me to run IE7 & 8 on the same system.  Perhaps that messed something up? I just wanted to verify there was nothing wrong with the code.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You said "I am using TredoSoft MultipleIEs "

I am having the EXACT same problem, and I am using Internet Explorer Collection to run multiple versions on one pc. Therefore, I conclude the problem is with Multiple IEs on a single machine!!

Hope this helps people, for your response helped me.

Comment: Yeah, I came to the same conclusion.  I was also running VMWare Fusion, which I'm sure didn't help.  Oh well.

Comment: IE is part of the OS.  You can't just pack up some random subset of system DLLs and copy them into a folder and expect it to work properly.  You cannot host multiple version of IE side-by-side in any reasonable way.  This is why Microsoft makes VPC testing images available to developers for free.  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en

Comment: I also ran into this, and it definitely appears to be a problem with a combination of MultipleIEs, IE7 Standalone, and IE8.

Comment: I have the issue with IE8. That said, I've also installed IETester so, indeed, that could be the issue. Stupid IE!

Comment: Thanks for this, sounds like the solution. I was also using MultipleIE... However, I just uninstalled that (using an uninstaller I found in the MultipleIE folder) and I'm still getting the problem :( Anybody know how to actually remove MultipleIE completely?

Comment: Yeah same problem Stupid , stupid , stupid IE . Why did the MS idiots create such crappy product that's hardly suited for web. I hope the world switches to chrome nd FF soon! I am tired of fixing stuff to be compatible for IE. Apologies for the long rant... but seriously screw IE!!

Answer (score 3):

Have found the solution. This is fixed in the latest version of Internet Explorer Collection (released 1st may 2009)

http://finalbuilds.edskes.net/iecollection.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link (Tredosoft's package was feeling a little dated); I'll definitely have to check this out when I get my Windoze development box back up.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... Strange. Seems to be a problem inside your browser/popup blocker...
What about selects on other websites? Do they work as intended?
Have you tried stripping it down further:

```
<form>
<select>
<option>blah</option>
</select>
</form>
```

just to pinpoint the problem?